# Huawei specific OS flavour creating weird files in my files folder

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services

Basically, I need to save some files in my app. For that, I use the directory returned by `getFilesDir()` method (like [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/internal)).

This works fine, but on some devices (I know at least two), files named `hw_cached_resid.list` or `aware_learning_data` appear in this folder. Why is this happening and how to avoid this?

**UPDATE:** Google search revealed nothing, but GutHub code search luckily found [one reference](https://github.com/SivanLiu/HwFrameWorkSource/blob/54f8e90b0aa54196b39ea89c7cbf0aa6ce4ccf1f/Mate20_9_0_0/src/main/java/android/rms/iaware/AwareAppScheduleManager.java) of `hw_cached_resid.list`. Turns out, it's from some (decompiled!) Huawei firmware, more specifically - `com.huawei.iaware` app.

> Huawei's documentation says the Huawei Mate 9 uses something called iAware System, a machine learning platform that learns your usage and preempt changes between apps as well as pre-loading frequently used apps.

(quote from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180129035230/https://www.geekzone.co.nz/content.asp?contentid=21292))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's a bug with built-in software of Huawei phones (some temporary files don't get deleted).

Thus, the only way to fix it (without contacting Huawei) - just to check if those files exist and delete them.